# Log file is about to be larger than disk, query still executing

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I have multiple databases with multiple millions of rows. I am trying to delete millions of those rows but am about to run into a problem.

My log files are getting huge and I am about to run out of disk space.

Database `A` has an `.mdf` file that is `10gb,` and so far it's log file has grown to be over `100gb.` It has been running the query for over 3 hours and I have no idea how much longer it will continue to run or how much larger that log file will grow.

What can I do about this? What happens to my query (that is still running!) if the log file consumes the entire disk?

I have a backup (shy the last 4 hours) of all the databases I am working with.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Trying to modify millions of rows at a time is a recipe for disaster. You need to batch your transactions: http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Thanks - I've realized that. Any suggestions where to go from here?

Comment: well, if your log file is going to fill up the drive, the transaction is doomed anyway. You could cancel and and work on a batched way of doing things. If you're desperate to let this one run, you could add another log file on another drive. Just be aware that rollback is single threaded and may take a longer time to complete.

Comment: Well from the time I posted, untill now, the log files have reduced my `4gb` open space to `90kb`. Awesome.

Comment: cool, best of luck!

Comment: Is there spare drive space elsewhere? You could add another log file now then sort out the (even bigger) mess later.

Comment: Flag as a dupe same issue, better written question with multiple good answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you run out of space the Query will rollback. You need to use transactions and delete the rows in batches and depending on what type of recovery model the database is in you will need to do LOG backups or Checkpoints.

Here is a stored procedure i built to remove milions of rows from an AX database in a safe way. Note that if your database is using a DPM system or something like that you will have to figure out someway to handle the LOG backups. Feel free to use it and edit it as you please.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Daniel Björk
-- Create date: 2017-07-27
-- Description: Delete rows in batches
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE csp_DeleteINVENTSUMLOGTTS
    -- Input parameters
    @DeleteOlderThanDays INT, 
    @MaxDeletedRows INT = -1,
    @MaxTimeMinutes INT = -1,
    @BatchSize INT = 25000, 
    @LogLevel INT = 1 -- 0 = OFF, 1 = Only Total Values, 2 = Verbose
AS
BEGIN
    SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;

    -- Logical Default Values
    DECLARE @StartMessage AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = GETUTCDATE();
    DECLARE @DeletedRows INT = 1;
    DECLARE @TotalDeletedRows INT = 0;
    DECLARE @Error int = 0
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(max)

    -- Print startup parameters
    IF (@LogLevel >= 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @StartMessage = 'Date and time: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@StartTime,120) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + 'Server: ' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS nvarchar) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + 'Version: ' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + 'Edition: ' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS nvarchar) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + 'Procedure: ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(DB_ID())) + '.' + (SELECT QUOTENAME(schemas.name) FROM sys.schemas schemas INNER JOIN sys.objects objects ON schemas.[schema_id] = objects.[schema_id] WHERE [object_id] = @@PROCID) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + 'Parameters:'  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + '@DeleteOlderThanDays = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@DeleteOlderThanDays AS NVARCHAR(32)), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + '@DataAreaIdParm = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@DataAreaIdParm AS NVARCHAR(32)), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + '@MaxDeletedRows = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@MaxDeletedRows AS NVARCHAR(32)), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + '@MaxTimeMinutes = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@MaxTimeMinutes AS NVARCHAR(32)), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + '@BatchSize = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@BatchSize AS NVARCHAR(32)), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        SET @StartMessage = @StartMessage + '@LogLevel = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LogLevel AS NVARCHAR(32)), 'NULL') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

        PRINT @StartMessage
    END

    -- Validate input parameters
    IF (@DeleteOlderThanDays < 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorMessage = 'Invalid value of @DeleteOlderThanDays' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' '
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1) WITH NOWAIT
        SET @Error = @@ERROR
    END
    IF (@MaxDeletedRows < -1)
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorMessage = 'Invalid value of @DeleteOlderThanDays' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' '
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1) WITH NOWAIT
        SET @Error = @@ERROR
    END
    IF (@MaxTimeMinutes < -1)
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorMessage = 'Invalid value of @MaxTimeMinutes' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' '
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1) WITH NOWAIT
        SET @Error = @@ERROR
    END
    IF (@BatchSize <= 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorMessage = 'Invalid value of @BatchSize' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' '
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1) WITH NOWAIT
        SET @Error = @@ERROR
    END

    -- Delete Logic
    WHILE (@DeletedRows > 0 
            AND (DATEADD(Minute, @StartTime, @MaxTimeMinutes) > GETUTCDATE() OR @MaxTimeMinutes = -1)
            AND (@MaxDeletedRows > @TotalDeletedRows OR @MaxDeletedRows = -1))
      BEGIN
       BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- Delete from InventSumLogTTS
        DELETE TOP (@BatchSize) 
        FROM [dbo].InventSumLogTTS
        WHERE
        DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartTime, DATEADD(DAY,@DeleteOlderThanDays, DATESTATUS)) < 1

        -- Compute totals
        SET @DeletedRows = @@ROWCOUNT;
        SET @TotalDeletedRows = @TotalDeletedRows + @DeletedRows

        IF (@LogLevel >= 2)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Rows deleted so far: ' + CAST(@TotalDeletedRows AS NVARCHAR(32))
            PRINT 'Total runtime in sec so far: ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(Second, @StartTime, GETUTCDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(32))
        END


       COMMIT TRANSACTION

      -- Only needed if you are using Recovery Model Simple or you have a small log disk that might fill up
      -- CHECKPOINT;    -- if simple
      -- BACKUP LOG ... -- if full
    END

    IF (@LogLevel >= 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Total rows deleted: ' + CAST(@TotalDeletedRows AS NVARCHAR(32))
        PRINT 'Total time in sec: ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(Second, @StartTime, GETUTCDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(32))
    END
END
GO
```